# How to get all possible node combinations with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5DY/1

My goal is to multiply each `person.type` node with each other:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<persons>
    <department>OUTER</department>
    <person>
        <name>john</name>
        <types>
          <type code="A"/>
          <type code="B"/>
        </types>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>doe</name>
        <types>
          <type code="A"/>
          <type code="C"/>
        </types>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>jane</name>
        <types>
          <type code="D"/>
          <type code="X"/>
        </types>
    </person>
</persons>
```

I started as follows to extract the values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <xsl:for-each select="person">
             <xsl:for-each select="type">
                <xsl:value-of select=".//@code" separator=";"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
A
B
A
C
D
X
```

Desired result:

```
OUTER;john;A;doe;A;jane;D
OUTER;john;A;doe;A;jane;X
OUTER;john;A;doe;c;jane;D
OUTER;john;A;doe;C;jane;X
OUTER;john;B;doe;A;jane;D
OUTER;john;B;doe;A;jane;X
OUTER;john;B;doe;C;jane;D
OUTER;john;B;doe;C;jane;X
```

How can I get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One one way to do this would be with a recursive template.

Start off by matching the `type` elements under the first `person` element, then recursively call the template the `type` elements under the next `person`, passing a "running total" as you do.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:param name="quote">"</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="person[1]/types/type">
          <xsl:with-param name="runningTotal" select="department" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="type">
      <xsl:param name="runningTotal" />
      <xsl:variable name="newRunningTotal" select="concat($runningTotal, ';', ../../name, ':', @code)" />
      <xsl:variable name="nextPerson" select="../../following-sibling::person[1]" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$nextPerson">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextPerson/types/type">
            <xsl:with-param name="runningTotal" select="$newRunningTotal" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$newRunningTotal" />
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamL3/3

Comment: I am pretty sure there must be a more elegant solution (especially in XSLT 3.0, so hopefully Martin Honnen will be along in a minute....)

Comment: This is very keen! Thank you so far. Anyways I'd be interested in @MartinHonnen suggestion for xslt-3.

Comment: /edit: what if I have a more complex scenario where I want to include fields outside the `types` list? See my edited xml above. i changed `type` fields in xslt to `type/types`, but that seems not being sufficient: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamL3/1

Comment: You can include the extra `name` in the running total. I've updated my answer to handle your new XML.

Comment: If I had like 10 attributes at the place of  `<name>` could I cache them somehow in a "parent" variable so that I don't have to `concat` those attributes on each recursion cycle? Or in any type of `Map<Integer, 10-columns-csv>` that I could lookup by index of the current segment?

Comment: You could potentially use a map. If you can't get it to work, you should really ask a new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Tim put the burden and pressure on me to try to find some XSLT 3 compact/complex way, I have tried to use accumulators plus XPath:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="person-codes" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/person" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/person/types/type" select="$value, string(@code)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="permutations" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="person"
            select="
                if (empty($value))
                then
                    accumulator-after('person-codes')
                else
                    for $v in $value,
                    $cv in accumulator-after('person-codes')
                    return $v || $cv"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('permutations')" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This seems to give the right output for Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 and at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamL3/4 for the latest input, but without taking into account the various other data to be collected as well, only the `code` attributes.

The accumulator based approach does even work with Saxon EE and streaming:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="person-codes" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/person" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/person/types/type" select="$value, string(@code)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="permutations" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="person"
            select="
                if (empty($value))
                then
                    accumulator-after('person-codes')
                else
                    for $v in $value,
                        $cv in accumulator-after('person-codes')
                    return
                        $v || $cv"
        />
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('permutations')" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A version that also captures the department and names and should work without streaming (e.g. Saxon 9.8 or later HE or PE) or with streaming (e.g. Saxon 9.8 or later EE) is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="';'"/>

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="department" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/department/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="person-name" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="person" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="person/name/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="person-codes" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/person" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="persons/person/types/type"
            select="$value, accumulator-before('person-name') || $sep || string(@code)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="permutations" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="person"
            select="
                if (empty($value))
                then
                    for $iv in accumulator-after('person-codes')
                    return
                        accumulator-before('department') || $sep || $iv
                else
                    for $v in $value,
                        $cv in accumulator-after('person-codes')
                    return
                        $v || $sep || $cv"
        />
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('permutations')" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, it does say in your profile "Now please start using XSLT 3.0 and asking xslt-3.0 questions so I don't get bored." ;)

Comment: @TimC, yes, but I am trying to develop and roll out a Saxon 9.9 based pure XSLT 3 fiddle with support for `xsl:result-document` and the time pressure you put on me ("along in a minute") is not something I can keep up with stuff like that not fitting the usual grouping we all have done too many times scheme.

Comment: I apologise for my frivolous comment. It was not my intention to put you under pressure.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it's reasonable for any follower of XSLT on the internet to come to the conclusion that you have infinite amounts of time (and, indeed, patience), or that you work at infinite speed...